# Honeywell T6 Pro Smart Thermostat doesn't hold temperature overnight - thermostat or HVAC issue?

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I have a Honeywell T6 Pro smart thermostat that doesn't seem to hold the temperature consistently. For example, I'll set the temp at 72 degrees with a permanent hold, and I'll wake up in the morning and it'll be 68 degrees, and the heat from the vent won't be blasting to get the house temp up. It will eventually get to the set temperature, and it does hold it fine throughout the day/evening/night.

- Only seems to happen overnight - temperatures during the day hold
- It happens sporadically - some days I wake up and it's the temperature that it's set at, and other days it's not
- Outside temp doesn't seem to have an impact on the days when it does/doesn't hold
- I also don't have a schedule set
- I have adaptive recovery turned off
- Not sure if related, but if I turn the fan setting to on, it doesn't force the fan to run (so I've just left this on auto)

I've checked with Honeywell, and they seemed to think it's an HVAC system issue, but I feel like it's a programming issue, since the temps hold fine during the day. Would love any input or recommendations on whether it's more likely to be a thermostat or HVAC system issue. Thanks in advance.

[image: thermostat image]

[image: Temperature sensor]

Comment: Would check though the menu carefully to make sure something like night time saving is not on.  A constant 4 degree difference does not seem like a heating issue, especially just at night time.

Comment: I've taken a look at all the menu items, and didn't see anything similar night time saving related. FWIW, the difference does vary, sometimes it's 2 or 3 degrees, the 4 degrees was the biggest difference I've seen so far

Comment: Have you set up a camera pointed at it overnight so you can see what happens? That might help you to narrow things down.

Comment: I haven't set up a camera, but I did place a temperature sensor to see how the temps have been changing (added a screenshot to the post). I've had the thermostat set at 74 (which is higher than I typically set it), and it hasn't reached that level in over a day. What I'm not sure how to diagnose is - is it not reaching that level because the HVAC system is too weak? Or because the thermostat isn't running the system until it reaches the set temp (judging by the regular dips in temperature).

Comment: When the problem happens, does it recover entirely by itself? Or do you have to (a) reset the thermostat in some way or (b) reset the HVAC system in some way?

Comment: It usually recovers by itself. In the past, it eventually does reach the set temp, but  kind of random when it decides to gets there.

Comment: Edit - also noticing my temp sensor seems to measure a degree warmer than my thermostat does.